# What does integrity mean in these sentences?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> 1. According to Hernandez, some streamers see live-streaming as a form of self-improvement, even without an audience. Many use it as a way to
>    feel more comfortable with the idea of broadcasting and sharing their
>    ideas, but do you believe this emphasis on being watched and behaving
>    as though you are being watched takes away from the integrity of the
>    gameplay?
> 2. ... You have protected the integrity of our democracy.

I was thinking integrity would mean honesty, but not too sure how that definition fits in these examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In this example, integrity refers to the original purpose or value of gameplay, and the pure (untainted or uncorrupted) motivation to play the game for the sake of the game, before that motivation is altered by external forces.  People may have originally played the game because they enjoyed the challenge, the strategy, etc. However, with players starting to live stream their gameplay, they are now aware that outsiders may be watching them play the game, and they may start behaving differently during gameplay, making decisions self-consciously or even  performatively (as if acting or giving a performance for an audience).  The integrity of the gameplay -- meaning the unadulterated enjoyment of the game itself that attracted players at the beginning, before live streaming became an option -- may be compromised because players now will start to play the game in a showy, comical, or controversial way that is more entertaining to onlookers, even if doing so makes the game less enjoyable for the other players.

2: Integrity here refers to maintaining the standards and spirit of our democracy and having all components of the democracy operate under one set of rules (as laid out by law). By operating under a consistent set of principles, we can assure that there is internal consistency and uniformity in how each component of the democracy functions and in how rules are applied and enforced. This means there are no double standards, no special treatment for certain people, no loopholes, and that both the letter and spirit of the law are followed.